# Configure ODBC on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, odbc, ubuntu-16.04, unixodbc

I try to connect ODBC with MySQL but I have some problem.

My install step is here:
a/ install unixodbc, libmysql

b/ find / -name 'lib*odbc*.so'

[image]

c/Configure odbcinst.ini

```
[MySQL]
Description=ODBC for MySQL
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcmyS.so
UsageCount=1
```

d/ Configure odbc.ini

```
[asterisk-connector]
Description           = MySQL connection to 'asterisk' database
Driver                = MySQL
Database              = asterisk
Server                = localhost
UserName              = root
Password              = 123456
Port                  = 3306
Socket                = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

e/Install odbc driver

```
odbcinst -i -d -f /etc/odbcinst.ini
```

[image]

f/Install dns:

```
odbcinst -i -s -l -f /etc/odbc.ini
```

g/Test if your system DSN was installed successfully:

[image]
h/Test connect:

[image]

I don't know why connect fail. Plase hepl me. Thanks

Comment: What version of myodbc do you use? Somehow this sounds familiar to me, and I think I might have solved it by simply upgrading to a more recent 5.3.X (?) version of myodbc...

Comment: I use 5.3.7, newest